# Android Studio export jar with dependencies

Tags: jar, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I had a project library in Eclipse with Maven and the generated jar included some libraries dependencies inside. 
Now I am migrating to Android Studio and I would like to build the same jar. I can generate a jar with the following lines in gradle:

```
task clearJar(type: Delete) {
  delete 'build/libs/mysdk.jar'
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
  from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
  into('release/')
  include('classes.jar')
  rename ('classes.jar', 'mysdk.jar')
}

makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar, build)
```

But inside the jar there are not included the libraries that I use in my project library. With Maven I can use the "provided" scope in order to include or not a library in my jar but with gradle... how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved with the following tasks:

```
task jarTask(type: Jar) {
 baseName="my-sdk-android"
 from 'src/main/java'
}

task createJarWithDependencies(type: Jar) {
  baseName = "my-sdk-android-jar-with-dependencies"

  from {
    configurations.compile.collect {
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }

  }

  with jarTask
}

configurations {
  jarConfiguration
}

artifacts {
  jarConfiguration jarTask
}
```

Comment: You rock mate. Saved the day. Just to clarify, you need to run "gradlew createJarWithDependencies" and the output will be in /build/outputs/libs

Comment: Can you please help me for above answer i am not getting desire output

Comment: This does not work for me. Source files are included as is and not in compiled form as was the case with 'Export..' in eclipse.

Comment: Its not able to find my source files (.java files). can you please give me the solution what i m doing wrong ?

Comment: please, can you check this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036702/how-to-import-an-android-library-project-created-on-android-studio-into-existing

Comment: Works perfectly. But, this is not applying proguard though. Any idea how to use proguard?

Comment: @nizam.sp Where do you add these lines?

Comment: While this works `as advertised` I wasn't planning on packaging my `java` files with the dependent `jar` files.  I planned on packaging my _`class`_ files with its dependent `jar` files.  -- I'll keep looking; but thanks for these clues.

Comment: @Alan - re: `where do you add these lines?` as top level structures; so just below the `dependencies { ... }` section.

Comment: @JesseChisholm Below the dependencies section.

Comment: Change `from 'src/main/java'` to `from 'build/classes/main'` and it will package the `.class` files instead of the `.java` files.