# How do I export dependencies along with source code into a single .jar file in Android Studio (gradle)?

Tags: apache-flex, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, executable-jar

[Different flavors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422722/android-studio-export-jar-with-dependencies) of this question have been asked and I would like to state for starters that none of them solve my particular use-case.

I know this is not particularly straightforward in Android Studio, but here's what I need:

I want a (gradle?) task in Android Studio to build a `.jar` which contains only the compiled `.class` files from my source code **along with** the `.class` files from the dependencies I define in my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.*'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.brightcove.player:android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

I *do not* need it to contain other files like the manifest or anything else in the `configurations.compile` directory. Basically, it needs to contain all the classes that would be found in the `classes.dex` of the decompiled `.apk` file.

Comment: so are you just trying to put the DEX file(s) into a jar by itself? And you want this to be a part of your build or the only output? And in your question you mention source code, so .java files too?