# How to import an Android Library Project created on Android Studio into existing Eclipse Android App Project, as library?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

What I want to do is to add this [GitHub - Custom-Calendar-View](https://github.com/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View) Android Library Project created on Android Studio.

I read a lot of questions and answers about, on SO, but none fits my case.
How can to this? 
Need to export a .jar from Android Library Project on Android Studio? if so, how?
Also its important to me to use the resources of Custom-Calendar-View library.

Any help?

Comment: Sorry this is my small suggesting you can use the below link and this is the Calendar Control developed using eclipse.  If possible you can use this one. https://github.com/Rajendhiran/AndroidCalendarWidgetLibrary

Comment: @RajendhiranEasu I will give it a try, if I can't get a helpful answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply compile the library into a jar file and then import in Eclipse. By Default Gradle provides building a jar from source code. See the example,

```
// Include dependent libraries in archive.
mainClassName = "com.company.application.Main"

jar {
  manifest { 
    attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
  }  

  from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}
```

You can check other solutions for building a jar with dependencies using Gradle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies)!

Comment: that way includes resources to jar too? this is important to me.
Also be detailed where to run this? I'm not too familiar to Android Studio

Comment: Yes. You need to configure the files that are going to be included & excluded! To run the gradle commands see the reference here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies or simply use this plugin https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar

Comment: where to run this? how to configure the files? I'm not too familiar to Android Studio. Please post a  detailed answer so I can accepted

Answer (score 0):

This is my small suggestion you can use the below link and this is the Calendar Control developed using eclipse. If possible you can use this one.

[image]https://github.com/Rajendhiran/AndroidCalendarWidgetLibrary

This has the swipe gesture feature as well.